# RAID 1 accidentially booted in AHCI mode

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-8.1, raid, uefi

I have two Samsung 840 EVO SSD's in RAID 1 ([Asus P87-Pro](http://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z87PRO/) and Intel Controller) with Windows 8.1 Pro on it. After a BIOS update, apparently all BIOS settings was reset, which apparently changed the SATA mode from RAID to AHCI (default). Although my Windows should have theoretically booted (from one of the disks), it failed to boot and went to automatic repair. After multiple repairs, etc. I realized that SATA config might be the issue and set it back correctly but again, Windows does not boot with a different error, this time it does not even get to the repair options, etc. screen.

Notes:

1. The BIOS does not show the RAIR volume or the the disks (if switched to AHCI mode) UEFI capable and I am wondering what is wrong and if this is the issue.
2. I have backed up my UEFI keys but it seems I do not have much of a way to recover them, any thoughts on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may have a good chance to work: Use the second drive to boot in correct mode. The one you 'recovered' let it unplugged and after everything starts, reconnect it and re-mirror the second drive onto the first (the altered one).

Answer (score 0):

After you updated `BIOS` or cleared `CMOS`, You have to change the `SATA mode` to `RAID` manually before the `OS` boots. However, If you forgot to change that, you should boot your system with `Windows Boot DVD` and click the `Repair...` then you should use the command prompt and run the below command in `Windows Drive` (for example if your Windows Drive is C: you first run `C:`):
`BootRec /rebuildbcd`

I had this problem and used the above command. So, my problem has been resolved. I hope that your problem resolved by that command.

Comment: Thanks! When I run `BootRec /RebuildBcd`, it finds my windows installation but when I confirm, it says it cannot find "the device". Running it with other options does not help either. Still, when it boots, it says File:\Boot\BCD is missing.

Comment: You're welcome Mahdi. I think that you didn't install the `Mainboard Raid Driver`. Please load your `Mainboard driver` first, then try again.

Comment: It is an Intel driver, which I have checked and according to MS, comes with Win 8. Also, I can dead and write files to the volume, so I do not think there is a driver issue.

Comment: Please check this http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9573-sata-driver-load-windows-8-setup.html for driver loading during windows 8 setup.

Comment: Like I said, I do not think this is a driver issue. This drive was used with Windows 8.1 setup before and even the recovery console detects it and can access its contents.